# Want records which match specific date should only check with the records having latest date

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table which contains logs of an enquiry. The table can contain multiple logs of a single enquiry.
I want records which match specific date and it should only check with the records having latest date.

Below is my code. Please help me with this

```
SELECT email_log.enquiry_id,email_log.email_log_date,enquiry.en_movetype,enquiry.en_unique_id, enquiry.en_movetype,enquiry.en_fname,enquiry.en_date,email_log.email_log_id 
from email_log 
JOIN enquiry ON email_log.enquiry_id = enquiry.enquiry_id 
WHERE email_log.email_log_date = DATE_FORMAT('2019-04-05 12:53','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
GROUP BY email_log.enquiry_id
ORDER By email_log.email_log_date DESC
```

Right now I am getting the below result.[image]

It is giving me the dates which are matching the given dates only. I want to check with the enquiry which have the maximun email_log_date registered.

In the below image the email_log_id 15 and 28 are the latest log. I want the query to check whether these two records matches the specific date. If it matches then it should return these records.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  For instance, which records should have the latest date?

Comment: add  also your expected  result  ..

Comment: why  two  records : 15 and 28 and not 15 only?  (15 seems  the latest)

Comment: @scaisEdge The enquiry_id 44762 and 44792 have multile logs. I want the email_log_id which matches specified date and should be the enquiry_id's latest log date.

Answer (score 0):

i think use of Max or First function of sql can help

Comment: How can i use max in where condition? It will give error.

Comment: if u want only latest_date record(single record ) first do order by email_log_date then use FIRST function

Comment: The enquiry_id 44762 and 44792 have multile logs. I want the email_log_id which matches specified date and should be the enquiry_id's latest log date.

Comment: Please read my second comment. I want all the records which matches the date and they should be enquiry_id's latest date. Your query gives me only one record. I tried removing limit but it fetches me only the matching dates.

Comment: select * from (SELECT email_log.enquiry_id,email_log.email_log_date,enquiry.en_movetype,enquiry.en_unique_id, enquiry.en_movetype,enquiry.en_fname,enquiry.en_date,email_log.email_log_id 
from email_log 
JOIN enquiry ON email_log.enquiry_id = enquiry.enquiry_id 
WHERE email_log.email_log_date = DATE_FORMAT('2019-04-05 12:53','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
ORDER By email_log.email_log_date asc) temp GROUP BY temp.enquiry_id

Comment: Bro your query gives me the result that matches the date but if a new record is there which have a later date than the matched one then 0 zero records should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your date  seems  you are looking for the 
record  for  2019-04-05

```
SELECT email_log.enquiry_id
    ,email_log.email_log_date
    ,enquiry.en_movetype
    ,enquiry.en_unique_id
    , enquiry.en_movetype
    ,enquiry.en_fname
    ,enquiry.en_date
    ,email_log.email_log_id 
from email_log 
JOIN enquiry ON email_log.enquiry_id = enquiry.enquiry_id 
WHERE email_log.email_log_date = date(str_to_date( '2019-04-05 12:53:00','%Y-%m-%d %T'))
```

could this mean that you want the log for the last date

```
SELECT email_log.enquiry_id
    ,email_log.email_log_date
    ,enquiry.en_movetype
    ,enquiry.en_unique_id
    , enquiry.en_movetype
    ,enquiry.en_fname
    ,enquiry.en_date
    ,email_log.email_log_id 
from email_log 
JOIN enquiry ON email_log.enquiry_id = enquiry.enquiry_id 
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT max( date( email_log.email_log_date)  as max_date 
  from email_log 
  JOIN enquiry ON email_log.enquiry_id = enquiry.enquiry_id 

) t On t.max_date  = date( email_log.email_log_date)
```

Comment: I am getting result that matches the date but if a new record is there which have a later date than the matched one then 0 zero records should be returned

Comment: then  you sample is not clear  ..   the query i posted  match the sample you provided .. SO is not coding service  .. but a question answer  site  ..  you should take a deep looka at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am talking about my query. Yours were throwing error. Anyway thanks for responding.